# How to run cd within bash script (outside of subshell)

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I am writing a bash script (called **gotodir.sh**) and would like to change directories during the course of the script, depending on some variables, say `cd /home/username/${FOO}/${BAR}`.

Just running this as is doesn't work when the process exits, since the directory was changed in the subshell only.

My shell is tcsh. (Yeah, I know... not my choice here.) In my **.cshrc** file, I want to alias the keyword *gotodir* to **gotodir.sh**.

I have read that executing the script with a `.` or `source` prefix will cause the script to be run in the same shell (i.e. not a subshell).

I have tried putting the following in my **.cshrc** file:

```
alias gotodir . /home/username/bin/gotodir.sh
```

but this results in the error: `/bin/.: Permission denied.`

I have also tried using `source` instead of `.`

```
alias gotodir source /home/username/bin/gotodir.sh
```

but this results in the error: `if: Expression Syntax.`

How do I accomplish this using a bash script while running tcsh?

Comment: have you got a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script and execute permission on the script `chmod +x /home/username/bin/gotodir.sh`?

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Yes, and yes. Unfortunately not that easy of a fix. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `source` a file from tcsh, it tcsh runs the commands. The `#!` is ignored as a comment because you're not running the file as a script, just reading commands from it as if they'd been entered at the shell prompt.

Your mission is doomed to failure. Only a tcsh `cd` command can change the current directory of a tcsh process.

But if you're willing to bend a little, you can write a script which runs as a separate process and outputs the name of the directory to `cd` to. Then set the alias like

```
alias gotodir 'cd `/blah/blah/thescript`'
```

**Addendum**

Adding an argument is possible, but tricky. Alias arguments look like history expansion, with `!:1` expanding to the first argument. But quotes don't protect the `!` character. You have to backslash it to prevent it being expanded during creation of the aliase, so it can do its work during the execution of the alias.

```
alias gotodir 'cd `/blah/blah/thescript \!:1`'
```

Additional quoting may be required to handle arguments and directories with spaces in them.

Comment: Interesting concept. So the script should return the path? How does one go about that in bash?

Comment: Just replace the `cd` in the script with `echo`

Comment: What if the script prints out other information? Right now it prints out error messages and polls for input.

Comment: If you print your error messages with `1>&2` then they'll go to stderr, which will be fine. input from stdin should still work. Only the stdout of the script will be captured and used for the target of the `cd`

Comment: Getting closer... unfortunately the script requires one argument. Is there any way to integrate that? As in, `alias gotodir cd \`/blah/blah/thescript $1\``

Comment: Got it to work with your addendum. Thank you very, very much!